# Vsc is giving an error but the python idle doesent?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I wrote a program, and when I run it in Visual Studio Code it gives an error but not when I run it in the Python IDLE. I have set up the environment variable but it still doesn't work. So can u please tell me how to fix this

This also has happened when I import a file and all sorts of places where I want to use a different file

This is my compiler.py file

```py
fileName = "file.txt"

file = open("file.txt", "r+")

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

for loop in range(file_len(fileName) + 1) :
    print(loop)
```

and this is my file.txt

```
hallo
```

When I run this in Visual Studio Code it gives this error

```
PS C:\Users\Harry Kruger\Documents\code> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/Harry Kruger/Documents/code/quicks/compiler.py"
hallo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Harry Kruger/Documents/code/quicks/compiler.py", line 4, in <module>
    file = open("file.txt", "r+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
```

And when i run ir in python IDLE it works and the output is this

```
0
1
```

Comment: Please if you don't understand something about my program just ask me I'm not the best programmer.

Comment: Where is the `file.txt` located? Have you checked the cwd(current working directory) when running the code under VSCode? Based on the pathname in your code, `file.txt` should be located in the same directory as compiler.py.

Comment: @Shiva hmm im not sure what u mean but it is in the same folder as compiler.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you run python IDLE in the directory `"c:/Users/Harry Kruger/Documents/code/quicks`. Therefore your code will pass because in this directory is (probably?) also the `file.txt`.
However in VS Code you seem to run `python` in the directory `C:\Users\Harry Kruger\Documents\code` where the `file.txt` is not present and therefore your code fails.
To fix this and run your code in VS Code you have two options:

1. In VS Code powershell navigate to the directory that contains the `file.txt`. In your case you should be able to do it by entering `cd "c:/Users/Harry Kruger/Documents/code/quicks"` and then call your code.
2. You can modify your code to use the absolute path of the file. Then you can invoke it from any directory. To do so you have to modify the `with open()` statement. Replace it with:

   ```py
   from os import path
   with open(path.join(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)), 'file.txt'), 'r+') as f:
   ```

   this snipet will look for the absoulte path of the file and open it.

Comment: your option 1 is easy but option 2 is greek so I'll just do 1